# the meaning of a shell script: grep 'vagrant@node' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys &>/dev/null

Tags: bash, shell

what does this shell script mean:

```
grep 'vagrant@node' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys &>/dev/null || {
  cat /vagrant/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
  chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
}
```

The part after the grep is not clear to me.

Comment: It checks if the text is in the file and depending on the result adds more stuff. Could have been written as `if`

Comment: thank you. that's the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 3):

- `&>/dev/null` - deprecated and discouraged bash syntax `&>`, it redirects both stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`. `grep -q` would be just clearer and also allow inspecting stderr for errors.
- `||` - if the command on the left side (ie. `grep` here) returns with a non-zero exit status, then execute the command on the right side
- `{` - start a group of commands